# VBA extracting randomly generated numbers from previously calculated code

Tags: excel, vba

**VBA**

```
Sub TrialOne()
    Dim loop_ctr As Integer

    For loop_ctr = 1 To 100
        Sheets("Capacity&Costs").Activate
        Range("LVanPurchase") = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"   'Generate random number
        Range("SVanPurchase") = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"   'Generate random number
        Range("d26:d29") = 0    'Account for large van's lead time
        Range("e29") = 0    'Account for small van's lead time
        Range("VanCapacity") = "=LVanCapacity + SVanCapacity"    'total Van Capacity
        Range("LVanPurchaseCost") = "=LVanPurchase * LVanCost" 'Large Van Purchase
        Range("SVanPurchaseCost") = "=SVanPurchase * SVanCost" 'Large Van Purchase
        Range("LostBusiness") = "=DeliveryDemand - DeliveryCapacity"    'Lost Business
        Range("TotalVanPurchase") = "=LVanPurchaseCost + SVanPurchaseCost"
        Range("LVanRunningCost") = "=LVanCapacity * LVanRunningCostperVehicle"  'Large Van Running Cost
        Range("SVanRunningCost") = "=SVanCapacity * SVanRunningCostperVehicle"  'Small Van Running Cost
        Range("RunningCost").Formula = "=LVanRunningCost + SVanRunningCost"  'Running Cost
        Range("Cost") = "=sum(R30,V30,X30)"
        Calculate

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Sheets("Trials").Activate
        Range("A" & loop_ctr).value = "Trial " & loop_ctr
        Range("B" & loop_ctr).value = Range("Cost").value
    Next loop_ctr
End Sub

Sub Optimise()
    Sheets("Trials").Activate
    Range("Minimum") = "=Min(CostTrials)"
End Sub
```

With the above code, I end up with a number "Minimum", and Range("LVanPurchase") and Range("SVanPurchase") are randomly generated numbers that are either 0, 1, or 2. 
"Minimum" is the final output, and the numbers generated in Range("LVanPurchase") and Range("SVanPurchase") are the input variables.

Now I would like to extract the actual values(either 0, 1, or 2) that were generated for "LVanPurchase" and "SVanPurchase", in particular, for the "Minimum". Is that possible in VBA? I thought of using solver and working on it backwards, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to do this in VBA?

Comment: What is the function/sub Calculate do or where is it defined?

Comment: Calculate does all the calculations above in the code from the random number generation to Range("Cost") = "=sum(R30,V30,X30)". I want to obtain the random numbers generated for the "Minimum".

Comment: @PaulFrancis, see Application.Calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to do some optimization, as the values are fixed until you recalculate the sheet.

First set up the Capacity&Costs sheet, then we recalculate each time, and then check to see if we have a new minimum. If we do, then save those values.

next we set the values on the trials sheet directly, so we don't get a flicker as we go back and forth.

only at the end to we switch to the trials sheet to see the results.

This gives a routine that looks like this:

```
Sub TrialOne()
Dim loop_ctr As Integer
'stop auto calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'set up the capacity and costs sheet - we only need to do it once, 
' as the recalcuation will regenerate the random numbers
Sheets("Capacity&Costs").Activate
Range("LVanPurchase") = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"   'Generate random number
Range("SVanPurchase") = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"   'Generate random number
Range("d26:d29") = 0    'Account for large van's lead time
Range("e29") = 0    'Account for small van's lead time
Range("VanCapacity") = "=LVanCapacity + SVanCapacity"    'total Van Capacity
Range("LVanPurchaseCost") = "=LVanPurchase * LVanCost"    'Large Van Purchase
Range("SVanPurchaseCost") = "=SVanPurchase * SVanCost"    'Large Van Purchase
Range("LostBusiness") = "=DeliveryDemand - DeliveryCapacity"    'Lost Business
Range("TotalVanPurchase") = "=LVanPurchaseCost + SVanPurchaseCost"
Range("LVanRunningCost") = "=LVanCapacity * LVanRunningCostperVehicle"  'Large Van Running Cost
Range("SVanRunningCost") = "=SVanCapacity * SVanRunningCostperVehicle"  'Small Van Running Cost
Range("RunningCost").Formula = "=LVanRunningCost + SVanRunningCost"  'Running Cost
Range("Cost") = "=sum(R30,V30,X30)"

Range("Minimum") = "=Min(CostTrials)"

For loop_ctr = 1 To 100
    Calculate ' generate new random numbers
    Sheets("Trials").Range("A" & loop_ctr).Value = "Trial " & loop_ctr
    Sheets("Trials").Range("B" & loop_ctr).Value = Range("Cost").Value
    If Range("Minimum") = Sheets("Trials").Range("B" & loop_ctr).Value Then
        'we have a new minimum: save the values
        Sheets("Trials").Range("C2:C27") = Range("LVanPurchase")
        Sheets("Trials").Range("D2:D27") = Range("SVanPurchase")
    End If
Next loop_ctr
'go to our results sheet
Sheets("Trials").Activate
'and turn calculation back on
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

It's also now in one routine, not two separate ones

Comment: This works half-way. I'm sorry I forgot to mention in my question that Range("LVanPurchase") and Range("SVanPurchase") each contains 26 rows of data. Is there any way to obtain 26-by-2 a table that has all the data just for the "Minimum"?

Comment: @KyungWonHuh, see new answer